# Keyboard keys remap

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, synergy

I have a Logitech K800 running Windows 8.

I have this extremely annoying issue where my keyboards keys appear to remap while I'm working. It's difficult to pinpoint exactly the cause or when it happens, but my " and @ keys first appear to swop, and after a while I am unable to type a # as it maps to something else then.

Programs I can identify I use is Netbeans as this is where I pick it up first, but that is purely just because I use Netbeans most of the day. I also have another program called keyboard-mouse-share which shares my keyboard and mouse (much like Synergy) but I have turned it off with the same result.

I know it will be difficult to pinpoint exactly what could be causing this, but is there a log or something where I can go to see what the issue may be?

Answer (score 0):

Doing some further research it appears to be a regional language issue. If you experience the same change your keyboard layout from US to UK or vise versa (depending on the keys swopping)